# .NET ORM Adapters: LLBLGEN vs nHydrate

Tags: .net, orm, c#-4.0, llblgen, nhydrate

We are about to start development of a web application in MVC3 Razor. We are looking for an ORM that has following aspects:

- *If you baffled or puzzled in a scenario you can
  easy to find a solution or consult*
- *Easy to manage updates and maintain changes (The changeset and features requirement will be fluent so we would have to be cautious about the alteration and addition in the database. This would be most in precedence)*
- *Well (Briefed, Easy and Updated) Documented so timely we can learn, apply improvements and the quirks.*
- *LINQ support*
- *.NET 4 Support*

After this checklist, I started digging. I have seen people are not comfortable with `Entity Framework` as compare to `NHibernate` because it has a history and `Entity Framework` is still developing. But, most of the questions here are asked a while ago and I am assuming there are many improvement done in the contemporary version.

There are ORM Adapters that works with both `EF` and `NHibernate`. Rather to use `EF` or `NHibernate` there are some good ORM Adapters which `LLBLGEN` and `nHydrate`. Hypothetically, both are as good as eachother. `LLBLGEN` is more in discussion than `nHydrate`.

> **I would like your opinions of `LLBLGEN` and `nHydrate` if you are
>   using one of them and tried the other.
>   Why the one you are using is better
>   than the other?**

**P.S:** If there is something better than both of them based on my checklist please suggest in comments and if it is already suggested in comments praise it by voting it up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

We develop at an enterprise application level and we use **LLBLGen version 3.1**. The application lets you generate code for multiple frameworks (nHibernate, EF, Linq->SQL, and their LLBLGen Pro). We generate to LLBLGen Pro Adapter Model because we have been using it since version 2.5 and we are quite comfortable with the ORM as a whole. We haven't run into a situation where the ORM limited our ability to accomplish a task.

*Their support is amazing*. Posting questions to their forum usually results in a response the same day by their staff.

Remember the rule that ***You Get What You Pay For***. LLBLGen isn't free, but the value of the software and support from their staff make up for the price (*plus you can get the source code too*).

I don't have any complaints!

Comment: Thanks. Did you try nHydrate?

Comment: @Ramiz No, sorry I haven't used nHydrate.